# Angular ui bootstrap unable to render modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to create a custom `modal` using `$ui.bootstrap` with the following modal code:

```
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: '../partials/modal/modalTemplate.html',
        controller: ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
            $scope.hello = "hii!";
            $scope.ok = function () {
                $uibModalInstance.close();
            };

            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
        }],
        resolve: {
            items: function () {
                return $scope.items;
            }
        }
    });
```

This is the modal template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title">Please wait</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!--loader-->
                <div class="loader" ng-show="showLoader"></div>
                <h2>{{hello}}</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <h3>footer</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

The thing is keep failing due to angular unable to find the specified template (the path is 100% correct).

```
GET http://localhost/partials/modal/modalTemplate.html 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:12185
sendReq @ angular.js:11947
serverRequest @ angular.js:11742
processQueue @ angular.js:16606
(anonymous) @ angular.js:16622
$eval @ angular.js:17913
$digest @ angular.js:17727
$apply @ angular.js:18021
(anonymous) @ angular.js:26495
defaultHandlerWrapper @ angular.js:3540
eventHandler @ angular.js:3528
angular.js:14110 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: ../partials/modal/modalTemplate.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.9/$compile/tpload?p0=..%2Fpartials%2Fmodal%2FmodalTemplate.html&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found
...
```

When I only use the `template` (**not** `templateUrl`) keyword, there's no error and some sort of modal renders, but it has no content except for the path to the `templateUrl` as a text. This is driving me crazy, I read all over stackoverflow and seems like everyone has different solutions but none work. Please advise.

Forgot to mention, I'm using the `tpls` version of `uibootstrap` as follows:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.3.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

EDIT:
My folder structure is as follows:

```
templates->login (contains the js file that should render the modal)
templates->partials->modal->modalTemplate.html (the template itself)
```

Comment: modal template should not have this 'script' tag

Comment: Not making a difference, still same `404` error :\ Should the path be relative or absolute to the `js` file?

Comment: check the location of your modalTemplate.html, is it the correct one you using in templateUrl?

Comment: I even moved the `modalTemplate.html` to the same directory as the `js` code that executes it. Same 404

Comment: is your partials folder a sub folder?

Comment: Yes. the tree goes like this:
templates->login (contains the js file that should render the modal)
templates->partials->modal->modalTemplate.html (the template itself)

Comment: how is your folder structure?

Comment: try this templateUrl : "templates/partials/modal/modalTemplate.html"

Comment: Looks like its working now. Which is weird considering the fact I thought I tried this combination. Thanks. Please consider to post an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: Its Ok @undroid i helped you thats enough for me.